# Rudin Theorem 1.20

Tags: analysis

Can someone please explain help which proposition or axiom the following step comes from.  I will highlight it in the proof.

$1.20\ (a)$ If $x \in R,\ y\in R$, and $x > 0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$.

**Pf**

Let $A = \{nx\ |\ n \in Z^{+}\}$.  Suppose on the contrary that there exists no such element that is greater than $y$.  Then $y$ is an upper bound and so there must exists an $\alpha = sup\ A$.  Then since $x > 0$, $\alpha - x < \alpha$, and $\alpha - x$ is not an upper bound of $A$.  Hence $$\alpha - x < mx$$ for some positive integer $m$.  But then **$$\alpha < (m+1)x \in A.$$**

It seems obvious that we can say that, but I don't see yet exactly which axiom or propositions allows us to make the last statements.  Can someone please help clear this up?

Thanks.

Comment: There should be an axiom that every bounded set of real numbers has a least upper bound, so that $\alpha = \sup A$ exists.  Is that the step you mean?

Comment: Not exactly, I see that.  It is the step from $\alpha - x < mx$ to $\alpha < (m+1)x$  Which seems obvious.  But i'm trying to stay in flavor of rigour and seeing what allows us to make such a statement

Comment: Isn't there an axiom that says that if $a<b$, then $a+x<b+x$?

Comment: Oh, actually I think there is.  It's in the definition of an ordered field.

Answer (score 2):

**Pf**

Let $A = \{nx\ |\ n \in Z^{+}\}$.  Suppose on the contrary that there exists no such element that is greater than $y$.  Then $y$ is an upper bound and

> so there must exists an $\alpha = sup\ A$.
>
> This follows from the least-upper-bound property and Theorem(1.19 in the book) which proves the existence of and ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ which has the least-upper-bound-property.

Then since $x > 0$, $\alpha - x < \alpha$, and $\alpha - x$ is not an upper bound of $A$.

> Hence $$\alpha - x < mx$$  for some positive integer $m$.

**Definition** Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, $E \subset S$ and E is bounded above. Suppose there exists an $\alpha\in  S$ with the following properties;

1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $E$.
2. If $\gamma < \alpha $ then $\gamma$ is **not** and upper bound of $E$

Then $\alpha$ is called as least upper bound of $E $ or simply *supremum*.

> So that "hence" part comes from the 2nd condition for the definition of
>   supremum.

(continuation of proof)

> But then $$\alpha < (m+1)x \in A.$$

See that this statement contradicts the 1st condition of the definition of supremum.

---

How $\alpha-x<mx \implies \alpha <(m+1)x$?

**Definition** An *ordered field* is a field $F$ which is also an ordered set, such that

1. $x+y<x+z$ if $x,y,z\in F$ and $y<z$
2. $xy>0$ if $x\in F$, $y\in F$, $x>0$, and $y>0$

It follows from the 1st part of the above definition(1.17 in Baby Rudin)

Comment: I'm more confused about how we got the last step $\alpha < (m+1)x$ from $\alpha -x $.  I understand the use of the definition.

Comment: I quote MJD's comment "Isn't there an axiom that says that if $a<b$, then $a+x<b+x$"

Comment: Yes, that's right I didn't see that.  I guess I should read more carefully.  But is that really just an axiom, there is no way to prove the relation?

Comment: @DavidJhoo, It is a definition. An *ordered field* is a field $F$ which is also an ordered set, such that

 (1.) $x+y<x+z$ if $x,y,z\in F$ and $y<z$ 
 (2.) $xy>0$ if $x\in F$, $y\in F$, $x>0$, and $y>0$

It follows from the 1st part of the above definition(Def 1.17 in Baby Rudin)

Comment: Ok Ok, I see :).  Thanks

Comment: @DavidJhoo If you are satisfied with the answer you can click the tick mark to mark this as an accepted answer.